# Uninitialized constant error in my controller after adding a presenter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, controller, presenter

I added this to my controller:

```
class HtmlreportController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @report = Report.new
        @report_presenter = ReportPresenter.new(@report_presenter)
    end
end
```

Then added this presenter to /app/presenters

```
# app/presenters/htmlreport_presenter.rb
class ReportPresenter
    def initialize(report)
        @report = report
    end

    def pass_fail(view)
        arrs = ['onemon.rb','twomon.rb','threemon.rb','fourmon.rb','fivemon.rb']

        arrs.each do |arr|
            shortname = File.basename("#{arr}", ".rb")
            newest_file = Dir.glob("ScriptResults/#{shortname}/*").max

            @reporter = File.readlines("/Users/username/Automation/Code/Reports/MonthlyTracking/#{newest_file}")

            if @reporter.grep(/test failed/).any?
                view.concat content_tag(:div, 'FAILED', class: 'results_fail')
            else
                view.concat content_tag(:div, 'PASSED', class: 'results_pass')
            end

       end   
    end
end
```

With this in my view:

```
<% title "HTML Report" %>
<!-- This is where the HTML Report lies -->   

<h1>HTML Report for Marines.com Daily Monitoring</h1>

<div>View the grids below for the following results:</div>

<div id="results">   
    <div class="results_grid">
        <div class="results_title">Xbox</div>
        <%= @report_presenter.show_credentials(self) %>
    </div>
</div>
```

But, I get this error when running it: **uninitialized constant HtmlreportController::Report** for the line **@report = Report.new**

How do I get it initialized to make it recognize the functions in my presenter into my view?

Comment: Please show your model code as well. backtrace is always helpful as well.

Comment: I don't have any code in my model. I haven't seen any examples regarding presenters where I needed to add anything to the models directory.

Comment: The question about your model is because the error is suggesting that your code cannot find your `Report` model *before* it even gets to looking at the presenter.

Comment: Followup based on BroiSatse and @Shadwell's comments, what is your report.rb that Report is defined from?  If not a model, then ?.

Comment: So I just generated a model which created a report.rb file with a class Report < ActiveRecord::Base. The new error I'm getting is an undefined method 'pass_fail' in my view which I'm looking into now.